# How do I create a whitelist for approved Gmails to access GCloud Compute-Engine hosted website

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, whitelist

Sorry for the basic question guys. I've essentially gone through a lot of the questions and cant find mine.

I'm looking to create a whitelist for Gmails that log in through google services, to access my website. However, I have to have the website hosted via Compute Engine.

Comment: Can you provide an example scenario?

Comment: User wants to access website >Website puts up security process, requiring user to be logged into one of their verified gmail accounts
a) > user logs in to verified gmail account on our whitelist > entry granted
b) > user logs in to nonverified gmail account > entry denied

Comment: Prompt your user for OAuth, limit it to the preselected accounts? It doesn't matter where you're hosting the server btw

Comment: Sorry, I'm relatively new and google just directed me over here. Wasn't sure if it was different using compute engine on gcloud or not so I thought I'd specify. Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 2):

Attach a `LoadBalancer` and `Identity Aware Proxy` to the Compute Engine instance and provide role of `Secure Tunnel User` to the gmail ids that need access to your app.

Follow [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/tutorial-gce) to learn more.